# How to optimize the size of data imported from Power Pivot to Excel

Tags: excel, postgresql, pivot-table, data-modeling, powerpivot

I have connected to a PostgreSQL database within my Excel file using ODBC connection and imported data into Power Pivot. After editing tables and adding needed measures, I am trying to import the data from Power Pivot into Excel using Pivot Tables. Although I am trying to use measures instead of calculated columns whenever possible, still Excel is not working properly and the performance is so slow. I was wondering if there is an effective way to decrease the size of data so Excel works better and faster?

I tried using pivot tables and mostly measures in it. Expected Excel to run normally since my main data is in the Data Model (not imported to Excel directly). I have also tried to remove unnecessary columns with many unique values (id etc.). I also made sure that Pivot Table cache is unchecked and it is not saved in teh Excel adding to the size. Still no success.

Comment: It seems you're confusing Power Query and Power Pivot. You don't use Power Pivot to import data into Excel, you use it to display Excel data already stored inside Excel in a compressed columnar format. That data isn't stored as cells though.

Comment: What does `I am trying to import the data from Power Pivot into Excel using Pivot Tables` mean? Or `performance is so slow`? Power Pivot already uses Pivot tables for visualization. If you try to expand a pivot table to show 1M rows, yes, just like every other pivot table ever created, performance will be bad. It would be even worse if the data came from cells instead

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Panagiotis Kanavos. In fact, I amnot confusing the two but used the wrong word "import". Of course, I used Power Query when I imported data from database. Now what I am trying to do is to display data as tables in Excel, as you mentioned. 
Now given that you are saying Pivot Tables with lots of raws will certainly have bad performance, is there any other way by which you would display such large data from Power Pivot in the Excel?

Comment: By the way, I also read a few articles mentioning Getpivotdata and Excel Cube functions to be used instead of traditional Pivot Table methods, but I doubt they would have anything to do with reducing table size. Any idea on that?

Comment: The very fact you say `from Power Pivot in the Excel?` means you're still confusing Power Query, Power Pivot and cells. Power Pivot is a columnar storage inside the Excel file itself, not sheet cells. You don't use pivot tables instead of cells, you use them to display aggregations of data, whether it comes from cells , databases or PowerPivot columnar data.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What you asked is what you think the solution would be. Are you trying to export data from PostgreSQL in one long sheet? Import PostgreSQL data in a specific place pre-formatted Excel workbook? *Analyze* the data you read from PostgreSQL using Excel? How much data? The answers matter a lot. Power Pivot is used to analyze data, not import it. You can export data as Excel using almost every programming language (C#, Python, whatever). `xlsx` files are ZIP packages containing XML files. There are many libraries that can create them without using Excel itself

Comment: Power Pivot is used to *analyze* as much data as can fit in memory, even beyond the 1M rows/sheet limit. It uses the same storage and analysis engine as SQL Server's Analysis Services and I think, Power BI. Pivot Tables are just one way of visualizing that data. Power Pivot itself doesn't load/transform data. You can't create Power Pivots without Excel as far as I know.

Comment: Power Query is the technology used by Excel and Power BI to load and transform data, eventually storing it in Excel tables or Power Pivot storage. You can create a Power Query script to load data from PostgreSQL into Excel and then take the same script more-or-less and use it in Power BI Desktop or Power BI on Azure to load local data directly to a model in the cloud

Comment: If you only want to load rows with Power Query, you *shouldn't* store them in Power Pivot or store them in a data model

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks a lot again for all the above clarifications. I believe your clarifications  added to my knowledge and made certain points clear for me which I confused. 
As for what I want to do, I want to prepare some financial analysis shown as tables in Excel file which is connected to database so that our finance team doesn't have to do manual job of downloading excel files, cleaning and joining them every time.

Comment: How much data is there? Can't they drill down in the pivot tables to get to the details? Finance users don't ask for long sheets of rows because they like them but because something is missing and want to do it themselves. No human can read 100K or even 1K rows one by one. Quite often they want say what's missing though. If they explain their requirements, it will be a *lot* faster to implement them in Power Query or in the Power Pivot model.

Comment: If they really need a sheet with all transactions in a long sheet, it's probably better to first load the date into that sheet and then create a Power Pivot from it for analysis and visualization. Power Pivot uses columnar storage - instead of storing data in rows, it stores the individual values for each column along with the rows where they appear. This uses far less memory, allows far faster joins, filtering and aggregations but makes accessing individual rows  expensive.

Comment: Yes, I feel what you mentioned last will be the solution. Firstly loading the data.